# How to get Android "tools" working again

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, ide, beta

I am using Android intellj Beta. 
Android SDK was working at one time.
After it downloaded emul, it now is throwing the following error:
Not using eclipse, so wondering if problem with Android BETA Ide and Android SDK not being in sync.
P.S. Now what?

```
 ./android
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:402)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:390)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:150)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:116)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not care. Removed the directory, re-ran updates, working again.